# How to access an object stored in a non-public google bucket using app-script

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bucket

Is there a way to access an object stored in a non-public google bucket using app-script?

i have this function which works for publicly available files, but i cant seem to find any documentation on how to access a non-public bucket?

How do i Authorize an app script to access a bucket?

```
function import_data_from_bucket() {

var url = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.txt';
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); 
var csv = Utilities.parseCsv(text, ',');   
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to download objects from a Cloud Storage bucket using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). If that is the case you could follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#rest-download-object) guide to download them all. To replicate these steps on Apps Script you would require to manage the endpoint and headers with [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) to capture the data. Please, ask me any additional doubt so I can help you better.

Comment: after some additional research, i have figured out how to do this (using AWS s3). I  found this bit of code by kmotrebski that generates signed URLs for aws here [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kmotrebski/gas-s3-url-generator/master/UrlGenerator.gs) which allows google sheets to pull in data from non-public storage. I'm sure a similar version can be constructed for google buckets, but i was unable to find it.